# All of my downloads are failing.

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, data-transfer

I am suddenly unable to download or open any files.  It says "failed" in my downloads folder for everything I try to do.  I don't have any blocks on, no firewalls on, updates have been done and nothing has helped.  Any suggestions?

Comment: How does "failed" appear in your Downloads Folder? Is it a pop-up message when the download fails, or a file named "failed"? Which browser are you using? What other browsers have you tried? Is there enough free disk space? Suggestions: in the Preferences menu for whatever browser you're using, navigate to and reselect the Downloads folder, even though it may show it is already selected. Also, Get info on the Downloads folder, and at the bottom under Sharing & Permissions, it should show your username with Read & Write privilege, with everyone set to No Access.

Answer (score -2):

First delete all your apps except the ones you can't then download the ones you want.

Comment: This answer is only valid on 4/1.